# Identify duplicates with True/False using Power Query

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot

[image]

Hello to everyone

I need help with the probler below.
I want to use Power Query and i want to have the result as the photo.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @horseyride explains how to mimic your Excel formulas in Power Query but there are usually better ways of dealing with duplicates that are more efficient and take fewer steps. How to approach it is dependent on what you are ultimately trying to do with the data though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to compare each value to the row below it

Bring your data into PowerQuery by highlighting the range and using Data ... From Table/Range and [x] column headers

Add Column ... Index Column...

Add Column .. Custom Column ... with formula as below, replacing the 999 with whatever you want to have for the last row (where there is nothing to compare to)

```
= try if [Category] = #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Category] then true else false otherwise 999
```

File .. Close and Load to ....

Sample code output

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try if [Category] = #"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[Category] then true else false otherwise 999)
in #"Added Custom"
```

~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

Another way to do it is with 2 indexes and a merge.  This might be faster for larger data sets

Bring your data into PowerQuery by highlighting the range and using Data ... From Table/Range and [x] column headers

Add Column ... Index Column...From 0....

Add Column ... Index Column...From 1....

Home ... Merge Queries ... and in the bottom drop down, select the name of the current query. Then click Index.1 on the top and Index on the bottom, with join kind Left Outer

[image]

Click the double arrows atop the new column and select [x] Category

[image]

Add Column ... Custom Column .. with formula as below, replacing the 999 with whatever you want to have for the last row (where there is nothing to compare to)

```
= if [Added Index1.Category] = null then 999 else if [Category]=[Added Index1.Category] then true else false
```

Remove extra columns

File .. Close and Load ...

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Index", "Index.1", 1, 1),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index1",{"Index.1"},#"Added Index1",{"Index"},"Added Index1",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Added Index1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Index1", {"Category"}, {"Added Index1.Category"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Added Index1", "Custom", each if [Added Index1.Category] = null then 999 else if [Category]=[Added Index1.Category] then true else false),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Index.1", "Added Index1.Category"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```